# An instance of a class named Queue can't be initialized in some ways but can in others and both ways seem almost identical to me

Tags: c++, c++20, template-argument-deduction

I was struggling finding a better title.
Here's the error: error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'Queue'
It seems to be a very common error that I am getting and I expect that it is a common error in general.
The problem occurs in operator<< :

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, bsTree<T>& tree) {
    if (!tree.m_root)
        return out;
    using Nodeptr = typename bsTree<T>::Node*;
    
    Queue<Nodeptr> q{ tree.m_root }; //this line right here
    Nodeptr current{tree.m_root};
    while (!q.empty()) {
        current = q.front();
        std::cout << current->data << '\n';
        if (current->left)
            q.push(current->left);
        if (current->right)
            q.push(current->right);
        q.pop();
    }
    return out;
}
```

In Queue:

```
template <std::same_as<T>... Args>
    Queue(Args&&... args) {
        push(std::forward<T>(args)...);
    }
```

It seems that the problem is that there is some difference between what the compiler deduces as T and the actual type of argument being different.
This is the only constructor in Queue, the other takes no arguments.
The problem goes away if std::same_as is replaced with typaname so there's something about this and I wonder what it is. As is with std::same_as if I use a function to return the address of the root node of the tree then it works but if it returns a reference to the private member variable holding the address of the root then again it's not working.
Strangely when I defined a Nodeptr variable inside the operator<< and initialized it with tree.m_tree and then used that to initialize the Queue that didn't work. It seems identical to using a funcion to get the root address of the tree(for example if I hadn't made operator<< a friend of bsTree then I would have to use a function) but it doesn't work and I am curious why it wouldn't.
using a simple typename... seems to solve all the problems in all of those cases.
I guess I will use that for now and I will come back to find out what's happening :)

I tried typename... instead of std::same_as... and I was expecting that the problem would go away...
I also just had the idea that the compiler probably creates references. To test this I tried this in operator<<

```
using Nodeptr = typename bsTree<T>::Node*;
    Nodeptr current{ tree.m_root };
    Nodeptr temp{ current };
    Queue<Nodeptr> q{ std::move(temp)};
```

So this worked so I guess that I should use some std concept to remove the references etc to get the bare type.
I tried this:

```
template <std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>... Args>
    Queue(Args&&... args) {
        push(std::forward<T>(args)...);
    }
```

I guess still not correct for some reason, this is giving the same error(after removing std::move)
Any suggestions are welcome, thank you all in advance.

Comment: The last seems the idea to take, but I think the concept notation is not applicable here. Try `template<class...Ts>Queue(Ts&&... args) requires (std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<T,std::remove_reference_t<Ts>>...>) {push( std::forward<Ts>(args)... );}`.

Comment: This one I didn't try but because I tried the other answer:
template <typename... Args>
  requires (std::same_as<T, std::remove_cvref_t<Args>> && ...) 
Queue(Args&&... args) {
  push(std::forward<T>(args)...);
}
If I understood correctly that's what std::conjunction_v is for so it's probably the same.
I just tried though, literally copy pasted this, then commented out the previous to use this one but I get the same error and I wonder why... I changed is_same to same_as and remove_reference_t to std::remove_cvref_t trying to make it identical to the other solution and it's the same error

Comment: But then this works:
std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<T, std::remove_cvref_t<Ts>>...>
I should find something to read to understand concepts a bit better, here I don't understand why this works and not the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So this worked so I guess that I should use some std concept to remove
> the references etc to get the bare type.

You can check with the `requires`-clause

```
template <typename... Args>
  requires (std::same_as<T, std::remove_cvref_t<Args>> && ...) 
Queue(Args&&... args) {
  push(std::forward<T>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks a lot... I tried this:
requires (std::same_as<T, std::remove_cvref_t<std::remove_pointer_t<Args>>> && ...)
to remove pointers as well, I don't know if it's needed or not, in this case maybe not because both work.
I guess concepts aren't directly applicable here but in a requires-clause...
I don't really know the difference